# Vs code/ Visual Studio Code Cursor styles - is It possbile to add more cursor styles to the editor through extensions or some othe way?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know these styles are the default options.
[Current Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czQPC.png)

what i have in mind make it looks like a ghost line style with some foggy effect, is that even possible, what should i look into to make this animation effect. Will post a spline design for reference (if possible)!!

I tried looking in extensions and also scouring the internet, so far couldn't find anything related to it.

It would look really cool if i can get it work for what i have in my mind(Spline design soon)!!!

Comment: set the cursor theme color to the `editor.backgroundcolor` and inject a CSS decorator at the position of the cursors

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1929